# jquery sliding list - best way to create one?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote a sliding list for a project.
Here it is:
http://study-wise.appspot.com/test/left_right.html

I have been wondering, is there a better way to do this?
Like something built-in to jquery-ui
Thanks
I'm wondering for learning purposes and also, if there isn't I'd like to post it somewhere so it could be used.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
```

CSS

```
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            a.move {
                z-index: 2;
                position: absolute;
                height: 28px;
                width: 28px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px #aaa solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration:  none;
                color: black;
            }
            a.move:hover {
                background-color: #aaa;
            }
            a.move.left {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            a.move.right {
                top: 0;
                left: 370px;
            }
            ul#shifting li {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 30px;
                width: 335px;
                border-right: 1px #aaa solid;
                margin-left: 35px;
            }

            div.slidingList_outer{
                z-index: 1;
                position: relative;
                width: 741px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 4px #24a solid;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            div.slidingList_inner{
                position: relative;
                width: 1200px;
                height: 30px;
            }

        </style>
```

JQUERY

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var current = 0;
            var total = 0;
            var wait = 0;
            var width = 335;
            var margin = 35;
            function next(){
                if(wait || current == total - 1) return;
                wait=1;
                $('li:eq(' + (current + 2) + ')').show();
                $('li:eq(' + (current + 0) + ')').animate({
                    marginLeft: "-" + (width) + "px"
                  }, 1000, function(){update(+1);});
            }
            function prev(){
                if(wait || current == 0) return;
                wait=1;
                $('li:eq(' + (current - 1) + ')').css({marginLeft: "-" + (width) + "px"}).show().animate({
                    marginLeft: "" + (margin) + "px"
                  }, 1000, function(){update(-1);});
            }
            function update(delta){
                if(delta == 1){
                    $('li:eq(' + (current + 0) + ')').hide();
                    $('li:eq(' + (current + 0) + ')').css({marginLeft: "" + (margin) + "px"});
                } else if(delta == -1){
                    $('li:eq(' + (current + 1) + ')').hide();
                }
                current+=delta;
                wait=0;
                $('p').text('current: ' + current);
            }
            function init(){
                total = $('li').size();
                $('ul').append('<li>End of lecture</li>');
                $('li').hide();
                $('li:eq(' + (current + 0) + ')').show();
                $('li:eq(' + (current + 1) + ')').show();
            }
            $(function(){
                init();
                /*bind events*/
                $('a.move.left').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    prev();
                });
                $('a.move.right').click(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();
                    next();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

HTML

```
    <body>
        <p> ... </p>
        <div class="slidingList_outer">
            <div class="slidingList_inner">
                <a class="move left" href="a">&lt;</a><a class="move right" href="b">&gt;</a>
                <ul id="shifting">
                    <li>123</li><!--
                    --><li>456</li><!--
                    --><li>789</li><!--
                    --><li>abc</li><!--

                    --><li>edf</li><!--
                    --><li>ghj</li><!--
                    --><li>!@#</li><!--
                    --><li>$%^</li><!--
                    --><li>ABC</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe it's a question suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I guess.. I am more interested in other ways to create it, like how would you go about creating the same thing, rather than comments about my code.. I will rephrase the question..

Comment: Agree with **F. Calderan**...Btw, there's always a better way of coding anythng it just depends on the developer. In this case I'd say start by separating your logic from presentation, and instead of using absolute values and ids etc, I would create a plugin.

Comment: I suggest you to make a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link instead of the code. The code and logic becomes more readable and can be tested easily also easy to make improvements.

Comment: I tried to post in jsfiddle but it does not work there?

Comment: I split it up to parts for easier reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html) if it does what you want.

Comment: This is the answer, I've been looking for, I am trying to remind myself that as a programmer, you are more likely to find what you are working on has been made by someone and is ready for use. This could have saved me a lot of time but I did not find it when I looked. :)

Comment: Glad to help! I used Scrollable on a project and was very pleased with its ease of use and flexibility.

Comment: @michaelhagedon the link in your answer is dead.